# Show Windows 8 Start Menu on the primary monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8, start-menu

I'm having the issue where the Windows 8 Start Menu shows up on the secondary monitor instead of the primary.

When booting the machine the start menu appears originally on the primary screen as it should. Sometime during the course of the day the menu starts appearing on the secondary monitor instead of the primary.

What should happen/initial settings:

Primary Monitor -> Win8 Metro Interface
Second  Monitor ->Blank

Starts happening after a few hours

Primary Monitor -> Blank
Second  Monitor ->Win8 Metro Interface

My Settings:

```
Display 1 (Primary):
 Resolution: 1920x1080
 Multiple Displays: Extend these displays
 This is currently your main display

Display 2:
 Resolution: 1440x900
 Multiple Displays: Extend these displays
 []Make this my main display
```

Card: Radeon HD 6950
 Catalyst 12.10

Comment: Open your graphics properties and set your primary monitor as Main display. From the Desktop right click and select "Screen Resolution"

Comment: @Moab, I already did that

Comment: What exactly did you do in there? There are several settings that can be changed, edit your question to include more detail.

Comment: @Moab, tried to make a little more coherent; is there anything else your looking for?

Comment: and which is your main display? 1 or 2? What's the graphics card? Which version of drivers?

Comment: @Sathya the point is moot now but I added some more details

Comment: @BrandonKreisel not really, there'll be others with the same problem. Having as much details in question helps sort out things

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's simply because you opened the Start menu for the bottom-left corner of the second monitor. So now it always open here. I had the same problem. Just reopen the start menu from the first monitor from its bottom-left corner and it will be fixed.

You just need to never open the Start from the second monitor.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks man, that was really bugging me

Comment: @BrandonKreisel Haha, no problem! I understand that :P