# Force windows 8 start screen permanently on secondary monitor

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, start-screen

I know the start screen can be moved using Win-PageUp or Win-PageDown, but is there any way to save this value permanently?

I've read similar questions:

- [How can I display the Windows 8 Start Screen on a secondary monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/480506/windows-8-start-screen-on-secondary-monitor)
- [Metro UI - multiple snapped view on one monitor, desktop on the other one](https://superuser.com/questions/505163/metro-ui-multiple-snapped-view-on-one-monitor-desktop-on-the-other-one)
- [Show Windows 8 Start Menu on the primary monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/493765/show-windows-8-start-menu-on-the-primary-monitor)

The anwser is always "open or move it to the screen you want". On my pc the position is only saved for this session, after I logout and sing in again the start-screen is always on my main monitor.

I tried reinstalling but the problem persists. Am I doing something wrong or has noone else this problem?

Comment: Can you make the other one your [main monitor](http://superuser.com/a/480527/138343)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [Windows 8 Start Menu Modifier](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1104241-windows-8-start-menu-modifier/) which allows you to set the startscreen on Display 2. Change the option "Screen".

[image]