# Windows 8.1 Start Screen Changes monitors but doesn't retain the monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, start-menu, start-screen

I have already searched on here for how to change the Windows 8.1 start screen to a secondary monitor. I found that it is Shift+Windows+Left Arrow or Shift+Windows+Right Arrow.

Although, when I make the change, it does not retain the change for when I close and reopen the start screen.

I have also found the following article:
[Can't change standard monitor for start screen (Windows 8.1)](https://superuser.com/questions/661380/cant-change-standard-monitor-for-start-screen-windows-8-1)

It pretty much entails that after I change the default monitor, I should not use the start menu button on the monitor i do not want it to open on any longer.

Problem with that is, I'm actually using a tool to remove the start button completely. (I do not understand why Microsoft didn't allow an option to keep the start button or to have it removed like in the original Windows 8). I also only have my task bar on my main monitor.

This article: [Force windows 8 start screen permanently on secondary monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/522661/force-windows-8-start-screen-permanently-on-secondary-monitor)

This gave me an option for another tool, although it seems a tad buggy.

So my question is, is there any registry edit or ANYTHING that would permanently attach the start screen to one monitor and one monitor only forever and ever?

Thank you very much in advance for reading this over and trying to help me. I am very greatful.

Comment: I will be honest it.  Does this problem happen without that tool and you might be the first person who wants to remove the start button in 8.1

Comment: yes it does occur without the tool. I installed the tool after I first experienced this.